# Where does the international bus from Yerevan to Tabriz drop passengers?

Tags: public-transport, buses, iran, armenia

Anyone know the exact location that the international bus from Yerevan to Tabriz drops in Tabriz?

It's a night bus and arrives at 2 am. For the safety reason, I'd like to know the location it stops so that I can find a hotel/hostel nearby.

Comment: What's the name of the company? - anyway, I guess they should stop at Tabriz Central Bus Station which is in Manzariyeh street.

Answer (score 4):

All International busses now terminate in the new Central Bus Terminal, Manziriyeh, Tabriz. It is located in the Southern part of the city.

Comment: correct and to be more exact it's here : https://goo.gl/maps/wLVNfg6hVp42